# python parsing csv file

Tags: python, string, parsing, casting, numbers

I am parsing a csv file where the first line is the header.
I want to sum the amount column according to dates, but am getting an error message.
To debug I am checking if the column is a digit as well as if it is a string according to the error message - and it is both.
What could be the reason for this?

```
def parseDataFromFile(self,f):
    fh = open(f,'r')
    s = 0
    for line in fh:
        #parsing the line according to comma and stripping the '\n' char
        year,month,day,amount = line.strip('\n').split(',')

        #checking the header row, could check if was first row as well - would be faster
        if (amount == "Amount"): continue

        #just for the debug checks
        #here is the question

        if isinstance(amount,str):
            print "amount is a string"
            #continue
        if amount.isdigit:
            print "amount is a digit"

        #sum on the amount column
        s = s + amount
```

Output:
amount is a string
amount is a digit
amount is a string
amount is a digit

Error:

```
s = s + amount 
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that `s` is an integer, you initialize it to `0`.  Then you try to add a string to it. `amount` is always a string.  You do nothing to turn your number-like data into actual numbers, it will always be a string.

If you expect amount to be a number, then use:

```
s += float(amount)
```

PS: you should use the `csv` module in the stdlib for reading CSV files.

Answer (score 1):

```
if amount.isdigit:
    print "amount is a digit"
```

will always print "amount is a digit" because you're not calling the method (it should be `if amount.isdigit():`).

You can be sure that any field you get by splitting a line from a CSV file will be a string, you'll need to convert it to an int first:

```
s = s + int(amount)
```

Answer (score 0):

s is an int, and amount is a string representation of a number, so change `s = s + amount` to `s += int(amount)`

Answer (score 0):

Something like?: (assuming column headers are "Year", "Month", "Day", "Amount")

```
from collections import defaultdict
import csv

sum_by_ym = defaultdict(float)
with open('input_file.csv') as f:
    for row in csv.DictReader(f):
        sum_by_ym[(row['Year'], row['Month'])] += int(float['Amount'])

print sum_by_ym
```